# Wordpress MS SQL Query with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have my wordpress page and I want to connect with an external MS SQL SERVER DB.

I am using a plugin that allows me to put PHP CODE in there. This is my code:

```
   $serverName = "192.168.2.3"; 
   $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"v3v", "UID"=>"sa", "PWD"=>"1234567");
   $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
```

**The problem is that sqlsrv_connect is not activated.** I have been looking for information and it seems that I need some drivers for my php version(5.6). I got the .exe file that install  .dll(the drivers) but I don't know where to put it. I mean, Where is my php configuration with wordpress?
With xampp it was located at PHP/ext.

If you have another solution to do this simply query I would appreciate it because I know that Wordpress likes to work with MySql but I have to connect with MS SQL SERVER.

Comment: Start by completely modifying "wp-db.php" to use the MSSQL PHP libraries. Then search recursively through all the files which contain SQL code and change those accordingly.

Tip: MSSQL doesn't have a "LIMIT 0,10" type clause, it uses "TOP 10" instead.

Basically, you have a long job ahead. Personally, I wouldn't bother as MySQL performs much better anyway

Comment: http://blog.building-blocks.com/technical-tips/installing-wordpress-on-windows-using-sql-server-2008-r2-part-2 Please visit this it will help you